# Loading Progress gif Image do not appear in browser until the pop up window is loaded fully

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, pageload

I am working on a report in which the user will select few criteria to generate report and click on a button. On this button click, a pop up window is opened to display the report. Below code is used to open the pop up.

```
string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=1000,height=700,left=100,top=30,titlebar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=1');";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
```

In page load method, The report is generated by executing multiple long runnign queries. So it takes lot of time to produce the result and in some case the page is getting timed out. To avoid the timeout, I want to load the gif image to show the progress, or i want to write the progress to client browser periodically.

But I tried both and both are not working as expected.

1. I tried to create label in ASP page and updated the status priodically. But only the last status is displayed on browser.

```
lblStatus.Text="Preparing eployee result...";
.....
.....
lblStatus.Text="Preparing Leave details...";
```

In this case only the last status update is displayed on browser, that too only after the report is completely loaded on the grid. In between (meanwhile the report is being prepared), I am unable to display anything in the client browser.

2. Next I tried to display a gif image when loading. but the gif is loaded only after the report is loaded on the page. But I want to load the gif while the report is being prepared in the background. And hide the gif, when the report is ready. Below is the script I tried.

Added div tag in the body element

```
<div id='pageloaddiv' class="pageloaddiv"></div>
```

and in the head tag, added the below scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(window).on('load', function () {
            $("#pageloaddiv").hide();
        });


    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #pageloaddiv 
        {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1000;
        background: url('../../images/indicator_verybig.gif') no-repeat center center;
        }
    </style>
```

I need a advise on how to achieve this.

3. Atlast I used the below code to write things on browser during the progress. But It worked well in my laptop browser. But when the actual user tried from his corporate PC, the browser do not display anything that written by Response.Wrtie(); Any idea why the Response.Write is no working in some computers?

```
Response.Write("<div id='mydiv' >");
Response.Write("_");
Response.Write("</div>");
Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">mydiv.innerText = '';</script>");
Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">;");
Response.Write("var dots = 0;var dotmax = 10;function ShowWait()");
Response.Write("{var output; output = 'Loading';dots++;if(dots>=dotmax)dots=1;");
Response.Write("for(var x = 0;x < dots;x++){output += '.';}mydiv.innerText =  output;}");
Response.Write("function StartShowWait(){mydiv.style.visibility = 'visible';window.setInterval('ShowWait()', 1000);}");
Response.Write("function HideWait(){mydiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';window.clearInterval();}");
Response.Write("StartShowWait();</script>");
Response.Flush();
```

Comment: So do you have a ActionResult inside your Controller to generate the report? And how do you call it? Do you have a html form with some options and submit the form?

Comment: This is tagged asp.net, so i'm wondering if you've tried using a scriptmanager, updatepanel and an updateprogress control. updateprogress controls basically show a 'loading' gif and fire automatically if there's an async postback. i'm not sure how you would use it with a popup but i am sure it has been done before. or show it on the main page and when it's done, show the popup.

Comment: I some how manged to load the script. But now facing different issue. When I access the site from my laptop, the script load first and then when the data is populated it hides. But when I access the same URL from corporate system browser (IE & Chrome), the script loaded only after the data is populated on the page and hides imediately as I am hiding in on page load. why is this difference ? any suggestion would be really helpful.